# @Html.Sitecore().Rendering does not rendering view even after executing without any errors

Tags: sitecore-client, presentation, sitecore-api

I am trying to use @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("--id--", Model.Property) to call render a staic view. It is not rendering on page.

**Layout:**

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("--Myviewid--", Model)
```

**Myview:**

```
@model namespace.Model
@{
    var list = Model.GetMyList();
}
foreach(var item in list)
{
    ---my logic ---
}
```

It executes without any exception. No errors logged in the log files. I even added a debugger to view and went through each step to see if it is breaking anywhear. Code is executed without any exception. But, view is not rendered on the page.

I also tried `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("--MyviewId--", new {Model = myModel})`. 
`@Html.RenderPartical` works perfectly but can anyone let me know why `Sitecore().Rendering` is not working even after executing without any errors

---

**EDIT** (copied from OP's comment):

In layout there is

```
@if(condtion){ Html.Sitecore.Rendering }
```

I confirm that condition is `true` and the view code is executed without error.

Comment: Do you have `@{...}` around the `Html.Sitecore.Rendering` in your layout? Or is it inside some html tag like div?

Comment: @if(condtion){Html.Sitecore.Rendering }. I confirm that condition is true and the view code is executed without error

Comment: "--Myviewid--" is view rendering or controller rendering? Have you checked whether the debugger hits the view file or controller? if it is View rendering try with Html.Sitecore.ViewRendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `Html.Sitecore.Rendering(...)` is not rendered to the html of your page is because razor works in that way.

If you start a code block (`{ ... }`), what's inside is expected to be code, not html markup.

What you can do is:

- Wrap what's inside `if` with any HTML tag, e.g.:

```
@if(condtion){ 
  <div>Html.Sitecore.Rendering(...)</div>
}
```

- Wrap it with Razor `<text>` tag, which will just render the text without the tag

```
@if(condtion){ 
  <text>Html.Sitecore.Rendering(...)</text>
}
```

- Add `@:`, which is equivalent with `<text>`:

```
@: @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("")
```

Read more in ScottGu blog post [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and  syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: After making changes as you suggested, I can see that view being rendered on the page. But when the partial view is returing data in  <script>--</script> format. It is not being rendered.

Comment: And for the performance, which is the effective way @Html.RenderPartial or @Html.Sitecore().Rendering(). I dont have any dependency on sitecore for data. I already have data that can be passed as Model.

Comment: I don't know why `<script>...</script>` is not rendered. This may be because of the fact that the only html tag is script. You could try wrapping script in some other html tag (unless you place it in `<head>` directly). If you ask about performance and you don't need any Sitecore mechanism, `RenderPartial` should be faster cause it doesn't need to do Sitecore extra work. But I haven't done any tests so I cannot tell you what is the difference.